# Laravel dependency version

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, vendor

Socialite plugin version I had didn't work, and I have replaced it. However, I found one that works and replaced it on live site in `vendor` directory directly, but I forgot to replace `composer.json`. Later that day, I pulled everything from live site because my local site started to give me some errors. After I did `composer update` logically, old dependencies were pulled, and now I have no idea which version I used.

Is it possible to find out a dependency version from files inside `vendor` folder?